# Can't change user agent php curl

Tags: php, curl, user-agent

I am trying to change the user agent by this code

```
 $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$exec=curl_exec ($ch);

var_dump($_SERVER);
```

It is not working. I want to send the request as a mobile phone. Is this possible.

Comment: Is your URL on HTTP or HTTPS ?

Comment: Can you describe `not working` ? Why is your `RETURNTRANSFER` value set to 0. ?

Comment: It doesn't change the user agent.

Comment: Are you sure it's not working?  Do you have access to the server?  Check it from that end

Comment: I set up a simple test page for you: http://shchuka.com/hosting/useragent.php - load it with CURL and check the output.

Comment: @AleksG you are right. Now i get the right output.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3"));
```

This worked for me and was necessary to post to NodeJs server since PHP's cURL did not by default provide one.